# Adding points on a map parcel from an attribute in the attributes table

Tags: qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.4.2 and a have a map of a subdivision with roads, road names, and lot outlines. I also have added an attribute, by using a join to a CSV file, of whether there is a structure (house) on a parcel. What I would like to do next is add a point (not sure if this is the right word) or an icon, on a parcel if there is a house there.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go through several steps. Please add comments for any clarification.

1. Create a copy of your parcel layer: To do this, right-click on the layer and select `Duplicate`.
2. Open the `Layer Properties` of this copy and select `Style` (tab). If it is a `Single Symbol` (default) setting, click on `Simple fill` and change its `Symbol layer type` to **Centroid fill**.
3. Click on `Marker` or `Simple marker` under the `Centroid fill` tree and select your preferred symbol (icon). An image below may give you an idea.
4. If you are okay with your symbol, then final step is to set a filter to display parcel polygons only which have structures on them. Click on `General` tab and find **Provider feature filter**. Click on the <kbd>Query Builder</kbd> and set an expression e.g. `"structure" != NULL`. (Change the "structure" according to your real data).

Picture below: setting Centroid fill marker (symbol)

[image]